# ng-repeat not showing data once object is updated from model window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show the selected data from model window using ng-repeat but its not working after object is updated from items selected from model window.

below is my code.
Bootstrap Modal

```
$scope.openModal = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'templateModal.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstCompCtrl',
          size: size,
           resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.items;
                }
              }
        });

         modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItems) {
                $scope.form.items = selectedItems;  
            });
     };
```

Parent page Html

```
<span ng-repeat="item in form.items">{{item.id}}</span>
```

If I see value of object directly it shows result but not in ng-repeat

```
{{form.items}}
```

Please guide.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DMFPTtFBDoy5ygDjCGua

Comment: i forgot to add the third params, i modified the code below ;) let me know

Comment: Oops, just dont dont stringify you array in the return :) ==> JSON.stringify(ar) return the filtered array directly http://plnkr.co/edit/VDFxMUf0RqQGSVHNqM5F?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
Dont stringify your array in the return :)

```
$uibModalInstance.close(JSON.stringify(ar))
```

to

```
$uibModalInstance.close(ar);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VDFxMUf0RqQGSVHNqM5F?p=preview

Comment: plunker is added in question

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

JS

`$scope.items = selectedItems`;

Html

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.id}}</span>
```

Comment: what is the difference it just an object. even this solution doesn't work

Comment: is it possible for you to post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a watch method as this example :

```
 $scope.$watch('form.items', function(new, old){
   var selectedItems = new;
   $scope.items = selectedItems;
 }, true);
```

or simply add this line after $scope.items = selectItems;

```
  $scope.$apply();
```

changed the code into the items property :

```
  return $scope.form.items
```

Comment: I tried adding $scope.$apply() it didn't work too. let me check watch

Comment: No luck using watch either

Comment: return $scope.items is to pass data to model isn't it ? Because I have two different object to get the data for selection and storing selected data to other object. Thus storing selected data to $scop.form.items and passing to parent window

Comment: could you try to change 
    $scope.form.items = selectedItem;
    for  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
let me know if it work

Comment: trying to create plunkr.. but data is not populated.. http://plnkr.co/edit/DMFPTtFBDoy5ygDjCGua